# how to close custom dialog class in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-webview, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with closing a custom dialog. I have two classes

```
 class 1->  AndroidHTMLActivity
 class 2->  CustomizeDialog
```

In my `AndroidHTMLActivity` I use java interface which is call from javascript, in this class i call `CustomizeDialog`

```
     public class AndroidHTMLActivity extends Activity {
     WebView myBrowser;
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
     myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "AndroidFunction");

     myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");


        }
      public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
         Context mContext;

          MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
           mContext = c;
       }
          public void openAndroidDialog(){

            CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(mContext);
            customizeDialog.show();
       }
```

CustomizeDialog .java

```
 public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog   {
    Context ctx ;
    public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
     ctx = context;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        MyThread downloadThread = new MyThread();
        downloadThread.start();
    }
   public class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        try {
       handler.post(new MyRunnable());
            }
        }
     }
    static public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

      // here i want to close this customized dialog

        }
      }
```

Here i can't use `finish()` method, I want to close the customized dialog box via the thread. Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Can you give me complete code?

Comment: this is  general flow of my code(main code will be long), my  AndroidHTMLActivity  loads the html file from local ,html file have the button click event which triggers means  i load the customied dialog , via java interface , i do some long process in  MyThread class after i finish my work i want to close the dialog ,i extend this class from dialog  and also i can't use finsh(),and dismiss() which i already tried

Comment: Open the customizeDialog.show() when thread begins and dismiss it when the download completes like customizeDialog.dismiss(). Use the same reference object for open and dismiss.

Comment: but i want to close the dialog in same class(customizeDialog) here only i made thread process and also i cant notify when my thread finish it work so

Answer (score 0):

Well I know this question is asked in the past and maybe already answered but haven't shared the correct answer but I still want to share this since I also got the same problem. Well here's what I did.

1st create the base class let say and create a static declaration for dialog.

```
public class Dialogs {
    static Dialog dialog;

}
```

2nd is to put your custom dialog.

public void customDialog(Context context){
        dialog = new Dialog(context);

```
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_login);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
//... other parts here
    dialog.show();
}
```

then the dialog dismiss:

```
public static void dismissDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

and on the other class to close the currect customDialog just call

```
Dialogs.dismissDialog();
```

That's it. :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

close it with outside handler like this

```
App.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dismiss();
                    cancel();
                }
            });
```

App is a application class